# Is there a way to toggle something out of localStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to have a button that toggles something in and out of localStorage (it's clicked once and it adds something to localStorage, it's clicked again and that something disappears from localStorage). I want to do something like the code below, but toggling "status" instead of setting it permanently.

```
  function setStatus(statusName) {
    localStorage.setItem('status', statusName);
    document.documentElement.className = statusName;
  }

  (function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('status')) {
      setStatus(localStorage.getItem('status'))
    }
```

This is code that I've used in something unrelated, and I know that it works. However, this sets the status, it doesn't toggle it. I'm wondering if there's a way to revise that code so that it does.

Comment: localStorage.removeItem('status');  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using [Storage.removeItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem)?

```js
function toggleItem(item, value) {
  if (localStorage.getItem(item) {
    localStorage.removeItem(item);
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem(item, value);
  }
}
```

Does it satisfies your requirement?

Comment: Oh that's an obvious one. I didn't know that was an option but why wouldn't it be? Thank you so much